# getRelationships does not always return relationships

Tags: java, neo4j

Depending on how I retrieve my node(s) the `getRelationships` method will either return all relationships (expected) or no relationships (bad).

Neo4j version 2.2.6. Using Java API.

```
:schema

Indexes
  ON :Lot(lot_id) ONLINE  
  ON :Lot(system) ONLINE  

No constraints
```

lot_id is always unique.
system has only about 3 unique values, not all lots have a system property.

Methods that do return relationships:

- `ResourceIterator<Node> r = graphDb.findNodes(LabelTypes.Lot, "lot_id", lot);`
- `Map<String,Object> parms = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  parms.put("lots", lots);
  Result r = graphDb.execute("MATCH (n:Lot) WHERE n.lot_id in {lots} return n;", parms);`

Methods that do NOT return relationships:

- `ResourceIterator<Node> r = graphDb.findNodes(LabelTypes.Lot, "system", system);`
- `Map<String,Object> parms = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  parms.put("lotSystem", system);
  Result r = graphDb.execute("MATCH (n:Lot) WHERE n.system = {lotSystem} return n;", parms);`

The pattern seems to be if I query on lot_id I get relationships, if I query on system I don't get any.  No idea why though.

Some additional information from Neo4j GUI:

If I run this query: `match (n:Lot) where n.system="SAMPLE" return n limit 1;` then I get my single Lot, but if I double click on it in the GUI nothing happens, no relationships are shown.

[image: Graph 1]

If I copy the lot_id for this node and run a query just for that node then relationships come back when I double click the node: `match (n:Lot) where n.lot_id="someLotId" return n limit 1;`

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `system`? Make sure the type you are passing in your params matches what is stored in the graph.

Comment: @WilliamLyon - system is a string. I can't help but re-iterate that the Nodes are always returned by the query; it's only when I call getRelationships that I have trouble.

Comment: Can you submit screenshots or/and data sample from Neo4j GUI, where relationships are presented for specified, found by "system"?

Comment: @FylmTM - I added some details from my experiments with the GUI.  My experiments in the GUI seem to match what I see in the Java API.  My ID's don't match up between screenshots, shouldn't matter.

Comment: I also dropped and re-created the `system` index, waited for my CPU usage to drop back to 0 afterwards so I'm fairly sure it re-built.

Comment: @Peter Are you sure that your data are correct? Ensure that nodes that are found via `lot_id` and `system` are the same nodes (have same id).

Comment: @FylmTM - You are right on, that is why my Node ID's weren't the same in my tests... Turns out that my `:schema` statement was important, as I don't have an enforced unique constraint on lot_id.  I have duplicate lot_id's in my graph.

Comment: use `:schema await` to wait for schema completion

Comment: Where is system and lots coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you have problems in your dataset.

Be sure that nodes returned by `lot_id` and `system` are really same nodes.
Probably you have broken dataset due to import issues.

Todo list:
- Use constraints on your dataset
- Use `merge`, to ensure that there is single node in database